# How could I use Dijkstra's shortest path for this problem? if the puzzle have no edge values?

Tags: python, graph-theory

Problem statement:

A 2-D puzzle of size MxN has N rows and M columns (M and N can be
different). Each cell in the puzzle is either empty or has a barrier. An empty cell is marked by
‘-’ (hyphen) and the one with a barrier is marked by ‘#’. Two coordinates from
the puzzle (a,b) and (x,y). Currently, you are located at (a,b) and want to reach (x,y).
Example:

```
Puzzle = [
 ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['-', '-', '#', '-', '-'],
 ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['#', '-', '#', '#', '-'],
 ['-', '#', '-', '-', '-']
]
```

Example 1

```
Input: puzzle, (0,2), (2,2)

Output: [(0, 2), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Example 2

```
Input: puzzle, (0,0), (4,4)

Output: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 4)]
```

Example 3

```
Input: puzzle, (0,0), (4,0)

Output: None

* Not an empty list, but the None object.
```

I've read about using a priority queue when it comes to Dijkstra's and I don't know how to come up with the implementation when there are no edge values and what visiting each neighbor would look like. The first thing that came to mind was adding '1' to each edge but I wonder if there is a better approach for this case. If anyone could guide me approach this problem would be appreciated. Also, should I consider BFS or DFS? I've been thinking to use BFS since I'm interested in finding the destination rather than exploring the whole matrix. Any insight will be appreciated and thank you beforehand!

**Update**

So I decided to do BSF for this problem but now I'm stuck. My queue seems to take the paths of (0,2),(0,3),(1,3),(2,3)...instead of (0,2),(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(2,2).
Here is my code:

```
def puzzle(Board, Source, Destination):
#    if Source is None or Source not in Board:
#         return Source 

    dx = [-1, +1, 0, 0]
    dy = [0, 0 , +1, -1]
    visited = [[False]*cols for i in range(rows)]
    distances = {vertex : float('inf') for vertex in range(rows)}

    reached_end = False
    distances[Source] = 0
 
    queue = deque()
    queue.append((currentRow,currentCol))
    visited[currentRow][currentCol] = True

    while queue:
        r,c = queue.popleft()
        path = (r,c)
        if(path == Destination):
            reached_end = True    
            return
        for neighbor in range(0,4):
                rr = r + dx[neighbor]
                cc = c + dy[neighbor]
                if (rr < 0 or cc < 0):
                    continue
                if (rr >= rows or cc >= cols):
                    continue
                if visited[rr][cc]:
                    continue
                if Board[rr][cc] == '#':
                    continue
                queue.append((rr,cc))
                visited[rr][cc] = True
```

Also, when should I insert the indices of each position in the path? since I have to output a list of tuples(starting with the source and ending with the destination). Any guidance would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your 2D grid is an unweighted graph as each edge has no weight. This means that you don't have to worry about edge values.

## How to find neighbors of a current cell

Assuming you are travelling in cardinal directions (north, south, east, west), create two arrays which store the change in coordinates.

```
currentrow = 1
currentcol = 2

dx = [1, 0, 0, -1]
dy = [0, 1, -1, 0]

for i in range(0, 4):
    newrow = currentrow + dx[i]
    newcol = currentcol + dy[i]
    print(newrow, newcol)

# 2 2
# 1 3
# 1 1
# 0 2
```

In your program, you will also have to validate the coordinates of `(newrow, newcol)`.

> If anyone could guide me approach this problem would be appreciated. Also, should I consider BFS or DFS? I've been thinking to use BFS since I'm interested in finding the destination rather than exploring the whole matrix.

Any of BFS, DFS, or Dijkstra will work for this problem. It's up to you.
However, DFS might be easier to start with. Search for its pseudocode if you are stuck.

Also once your algorithm finds the destination goal, you will have to backtrack to obtain the path taken. [One of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73167621/17627866) can be useful if you are stuck on this part.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll start with that in mind.